# After migration from Hibernate 3 to 4: All Connection in UCP in use

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, migration, connection-pooling

I've updated Hibernate from:

- hibernate-entitymanager 3.6.9.Final
- hibernate-jpamodelgen 1.2.0.Final

to:

- hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.11.Final
- hibernate-jpamodelgen 4.3.11.Final

I left 'hibernate-validator' at 4.3.0.Final

But now if I run my junit tests, I receive an exception if I run multiple db-tests in one run.

```
Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: All connections  
in the Universal Connection Pool are in use
```

If I run a single test, it works as expected, but as soon as I start multiple tests which use the connectionpool, it doesn't work anymore.

I've checked migration-guides but couldn't find a change I had to make.
I've already changed the `connectionWaitTimeout` to 180 but it doesn't help.

What could be the cause?

Sidenote: I've also updated from Spring 3 to spring 4, but that works as expected. Also if I run my tests with spring 4 and hibernate 3, it works as expected.

Comment: What are your hibernate configuration settings for these tests? Do you close the connection after each test? You can increase the number of connections by the following property <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>

Comment: Please add your configuration, especially they one regarding the hibernate and transaction setup.